# How to pass a char array as a parameter in C++

Tags: c++

I am a [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) developer having trouble with these types.

Error message:

> invalid conversion from 'uint8_t*' {aka 'unsigned char*'} to 'uint8_t' {aka 'unsigned char'} [-fpermissive]

```
#include "TpsEspNow.h"

uint8_t receiverAddress[] = {0x34, 0x85, 0x18, 0xA9, 0xFB, 0xF0};
TpsEspNow tpsEspNow;

void setup() {
  tpsEspNow.setup(receiverAddress);
}
```

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <esp_now.h>

class TpsEspNow {
    public:
        TpsEspNow();
        void setup(uint8_t recAddr){
            receiverAddress = recAddr;
        };
    private:
        uint8_t receiverAddress;
}
```

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have 3 books.  It is still very difficult for me to understand.  Would you please offer a code snippet to fix im issue?

Comment: Using a `std::vector<uint8_t>` would make this much easier. Once you fix the type mismatch in this code you'll run into the issue that arrays can't be assigned to one another, you'll need to copy the values and will probably also want to pass the size of the array to facilitate that. `std::vector` solves all of those issues.

Comment: What is the context? [Arduino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino)? [ESP8266](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP8266)? [ESP32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP32)? Some kind of embedded system? What do *WiFi.h* and *esp_now.h* belong to? [ESP-NOW](https://github.com/espressif/esp-now/tree/master)? Why are the two includes necessary?

Comment: [A question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67510547/sending-data-over-esp-now) with the same includes ([ESP32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP32) and [Arduino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino)).

Comment: @RetiredNinja I will use the vector approach.  Thank you.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I should have left those includes out of the example code.  They were not necessary to the problem at hand. Thank you for the link to the ESP question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax note: in C++, the class must be followed with a semi-colon.

Raw arrays are generally passed as pointers to their first elements in C++, but because this pointer has no understanding of the size of the array it's pointing to, you also need to pass an array size.

Raw arrays in C++ also cannot be assigned to each other, so we have to explicitly copy the contents of the argument into the member variable.

But your member variable is not a raw array. It needs to be one for this to work. If you don't know the size at compile time, you need to dynamically allocate the memory for it, so the member variable must be a pointer.

```
#include "TpsEspNow.h"

uint8_t receiverAddress[] = {0x34, 0x85, 0x18, 0xA9, 0xFB, 0xF0};
TpsEspNow tpsEspNow;

void setup() {
  tpsEspNow.setup(receiverAddress);
}
```

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <esp_now.h>

class TpsEspNow {
    public:
        TpsEspNow();
        void setup(uint8_t *recAddr, std::size_t len){
            receiverAddress = new uint8_t[len];
      
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                receiverAddress[i] = recAddr[i];
            }
        };
    private:
        uint8_t *receiverAddress;
};
```

Now, this has a problem. You need a destructor to deallocate that memory, and since setup may be called multiple times, you need to free the memory `receiverAddress` points to each time you call it.

You probably also want to store a member variable to be able to determine how long the dynamically allocated array is.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <esp_now.h>

class TpsEspNow {
    public:
        TpsEspNow();
        void setup(uint8_t *recAddr, std::size_t len){
            length = len;

            if (receiverAddress) delete[] receiverAddress;

            receiverAddress = new uint8_t[len];
      
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                receiverAddress[i] = recAddr[i];
            }
        };

        ~TpsEspNow() { if (receiverAddress) delete[] receiverAddress; }
    private:
        uint8_t *receiverAddress;
        std::size_t length;
};
```

If `receiverAddress` and `recAddr` are both pointers, why not simply do the following?

```
class TpsEspNow {
    public:
        TpsEspNow();
        void setup(uint8_t *recAddr){
            receiverAddress = recAddr;
        };
    private:
        uint8_t *receiverAddress;
};
```

Well, that compiles, but it poses a huge problem. An instance of `TpsEspNow` now possesses a pointer to a chunk of memory that lives somewhere else in the program, over which it has no control. The *lifetime* of that memory may be shorter than the instance's lifetime, and that memory could become invalid, leading to [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

If your instance makes a copy of the data, that problem does not exist.

To avoid other issues, read up on the [Rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). The above code does not fully implement this.

*Of course, this is all much simpler if you use `std::vector>` as suggested in comments. A vector will have an understanding of how many elements are in it, and memory allocation will be handled for you.*

Comment: Chris, thank you for taking the time to post that great explanation.